# How to install ob-kb-funnel plugin in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have installed Elasticsearch and Kibana locally on Linux OS.
Now I am trying to install a plugin, named "ob-kb-funnel" for funnel analysis in kibana, using the following command:

```
> bin/kibana-plugin install
> https://github.com/outbrain/ob-kb-funnel/releases/download/v5.1.1/ob-kb-funnel.zip
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "No valid url specified"
```

What can I do to fix this as there is no detail documentation of installing this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

from the  top of my mind, seems you are  sending your command on two lines.
that is,

```
bin/kibana-plugin install
```

and next,

```
https://github.com/outbrain/ob-kb-funnel/releases/download/v5.1.1/ob-kb-funnel.zip
```

if that's the case, then I think the reason it's showing the error is because you are not telling the terminal it's a multiline instruction.
I suggest you try this instead.

```
bin/kibana-plugin install \
```

and then

```
https://github.com/outbrain/ob-kb-funnel/releases/download/v5.1.1/ob-kb-funnel.zip
```

notice the anti-slash at the end of the first line. This indicates to the terminal that this instruction isn't yet finished and the next part is on the next line.